# Image Processing in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I change this image:

[image]

into this image:

[image]

I am using opencv in python and have tried erosion dilation and smoothing but can not get the result.

Comment: Try using adaptive thresholding: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: Specifically, Otsu's binarization is relevant for your problem

Comment: Otsu's binarization after gaussian filtering seems good with only a few black spots left. Will these go away with erosion ?

Comment: Try it and let me know :)

Comment: putting a strong threshold is sufficient for that i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep smooth edges,

- enlarge the image by some factor (3 or 4), with interpolation;
- binarize;
- smooth;
- reduce by decimation.

[image]

Comment: by far the best solution to me +1 !!

Answer (score 0):

Directly using the example from [OpenCV's Image Thresholding Example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('roxy.png',0)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
_,res = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
cv.imwrite('roxy_result.png', res)
```

I got the following result. Little more experimenting should get you what you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a threshold value for the image. Try this code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('input.png',0)
threshold = 20
img = cv2.threshold(img, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv.imwrite('output.png', img)
```

Here I have manually set a threshold value (20) since automatic threshold value calculating algorithms give some noise. Remember that it is not a good practice to set manual value for the threshold. I assumed that this is a specific task.

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improvise. Instead of manually applying a threshold by trial-and-error I chose a threshold value that is 1/3 of the median value of the given grayscale image.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Desktop\roxy.png', 0)

th = int(max(0, (1.0 - 0.66) * np.median(img)))
ret, res = cv2.threshold(img, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Desktop\roxy1res.png', res)
```

[image]

In this image you can see numerous dots which can be removed by performing median filtering:

```
median = cv2.medianBlur(res, 3)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Desktop\roxy2median.png', median)
```

[image]

But now the letter R has some gaps which can be reconstructed by morphological erosion using a custom-made kernel. You can use the built-in kernels but the resulting image won't be as good as you expect.

```
kernel = np.array([1,1,1],  dtype=np.int8)
kernel = kernel.reshape((1, 3))

erosion = cv2.erode(median, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Desktop\roxy3erosion.png', erosion)
```

[image]

The letter R still is not perfect, but you can fine tune it.